# G_SIGNAL using multiple arguments

Tags: c++, signals, glib

I'm struggling to understand how g_signalling works when trying to add multiple parameters. From what I understand, I specify how many paremeters I want using g_signal_new. In the following case, I want a single integer to be passed in.

```
g_signal_new ("add-client", G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,0, NULL, 
NULL, g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__INT, G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_INT);
```

I connect the signal. I want to also pass in another argument here:

```
g_signal_connect (pipeline, "add-client", G_CALLBACK (add_client), arg1);
```

...elsewhere the signal is emitted.

```
gint client_id = 5; //as an example
g_signal_emit_by_name(pipeline, "add-client", 0, client_id);
```

... the callback

```
static void add_client(guint client_id, gpointer arg1){
   g_print("Adding Client!\n");
   g_print("%d\n",client_id);
}
```

The client id comes out as non-deterministic garbage.

1. Why can't I send this value with the signal.
2. Can arg1 also be sent in this fashion? I'm also getting garbage for it too.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer with an MCVE, but my first thought it that your handler should be `static void add_client(GObject* sender, gint client_id, gpointer user_data)`, and you shouldn't be trying to create a new signal for G_TYPE_OBJECT, it should be in the class_init function for your own type.

Comment: Here is a quick example generated from Vala: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/f4RT4qo77yG6cPXu6eFu5g

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! You're a life saver.